# Why does colab not recognize one of my source files?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

According to the following image, colab has recognized one of my source files and has not recognized another one. why?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove `__pycache__` directory, and refresh the environment.

If it doesn't work, try to import the problematic module like this:

```
from importlib.machinery import SourceFileLoader


module = SourceFileLoader("my_models", "/content/drive/MyDrive/ColabNotebook/my_models.py").load_module()
```

Let me know if it's helped.